# display input field using JavaScript onMouseOver

Tags: javascript

I am having some question about how do I using the JavaScript onMouseOver function to make the hover effect appear?
If you would like to see a live example, you can have a look to notion.com calendar section. As the idea is something similar when hovering, the add button will appear while you hovering the calendar box.

Picture of notion.com
[image]

My version: (I have no idea what happened to the onMouseOver is displaying)
[image]

My code:

```
if (counter == day){
htmlContent += "<div class='blank' onMouseOver='<input type='file'>'' "+ "onMouseOut='<input type='file'>'"+ counter + "</div>";

}else{
```

Comment: share more code, more about htmlContent variable, where did you write it to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an HTML tag in the onMouseOver attribute. Instead it must contain javascript code, for instance a call to a named function in the global scope, or an anonymous function.

Also, your code contains improperly nested quotes, which is why the browser is not rendering it in the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have added HTML in the onMouseOver attribute but it expects a javascript code. 
Change your code like below,

```
function appendInput(e){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="file"/>';
    e.target.appendChild(div.firstChild);
}
if (counter == day){
     htmlContent += "<div class='blank' onMouseOver='appendInput(event)'>"+counter+"</div>";
}
```